# Explaining C declarations in Rust

Tags: pointers, rust

I need to rewrite these C declarations in Go and Rust for a set of practice problems I am working on. I figured out the Go part, but I am having trouble with the Rust part. Any ideas or help to write these in Rust?

1. double *a[n];
2. double (*b)[n];
3. double (*c[n])();
4. double (*d())[n];

Comment: why did you delete the containts of the entire question with title? if you want to delete the question, delete the question, not the contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `n` is a constant:

```
let a: [*mut f64, ..n];           // double *a[n];
let b: *mut [f64, ..n];           // double (*b)[n];
let c: [fn() -> f64, ..n];        // double (*c[n])();
fn d() -> *mut [f64, ..n];        // double (*d())[n];
```

These are rather awkward and unusual types in any language. Rust's syntax, however, makes these declarations a lot easier to read than C's syntax does.

Note that `d` in C is a function declaration. In Rust, external function declarations are only allowed in `extern` blocks (see [the FFI guide](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-ffi.html)).

Comment: @AdrianRuiz: Check my edit, my initial translation of `d` was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on what, exactly, the `*` is for.  For example, is the first one being used as an array of pointers to `double`s, or is it an array of arrays of `double`s?  Are the pointers nullable or not?

Also, is `n` a constant or not?  If it is, then you want an array; if it's not, you want a `Vec`.

Also also, are these global or local declarations?  Are they function arguments?  There's different syntax involved for each.

Frankly, without more context, it's *impossible* to answer this question with any accuracy.  Instead, I will give you the following:

- The [Rust documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/) contains all the information you'll need, although it's spread out a bit.  Check the reference and any appropriate-looking guides.  The [FFI Guide](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-ffi.html) is probably worth looking at.
- [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) is a website that will unpick C declarations if that's the part you're having difficulty with.  Just note that you'll have to remove the semicolon and the `n` or it won't parse.
- The floating point types in Rust are `f32` and `f64`, depending on whether you're using `float` or `double`.  Also, don't get caught: `int` in Rust **is not** equivalent to `int` in C.  Prefer explicitly-sized types like `i32` or `u64`, or types from `libc` like `c_int`.  `int` and `uint` should **only** be used with explicitly pointer-sized values.
- Normally, you'd write a reference to a `T` as `&T` or `&mut T`, depending on desired mutability (default in C is mutable, default in Rust is *immutable*).
- If you want a nullable reference, use `Option<&T>`.
- If you are trying to use these in a context where you start getting complaints about needing "lifetimes"... well, you're just going to have to learn the language.  At that point, simple translation isn't going to work very well.
- In Rust, array types are written as brackets *around* the element type.  So an "array of `double`s" would be `[f64]`, an array of size `n` would be `[f64, ..n]`.  Typically, however, the *actual* equivalent to, say, `double[]` in C would be `&[f64]`; that is, a reference to an array, rather then the actual *contents* of the array.
- Use of "raw pointers" is *heavily* discouraged in Rust, and you cannot use them meaningfully outside of unsafe code.  In terms of syntax, a pointer to `T` is `*const T` or `*mut T`, depending on whether it's a pointer to constant or mutable data.
- Function pointers are just written as `fn (Args...) -> Result`.  So a function that takes nothing and returns a double would be `fn () -> f64`.